# Wordpress custom register form errors filters and prev values

Tags: wordpress, filter, registration, frontend

I created a front end registration form, I used the filters 'registration_errors' to customize the messages.

After WP detects the error and use 'wp-redirect' to return to the registration page and display an error if the email or the user exists for example.

My question is: how I can keep the previous values that generated the error.

¿JS?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: yes js would be a good idea, another is to post to the same page, you can grab the variables using `$_POST`

Comment: My form action is (action="<?php echo site_url('wp-login.php?action=register', 'login_post') ?>"), I'm actually doing "POST" in wp-login, I can do two actions "POST"?

Comment: no, unless you repeat the action, as i said you can do a custom action on the page you are logging in with or hook into login and save the values somewhere e.g. `$_SESSION` there is no way to pull the post variables otherwise.

Comment: Done! Thank you, one more question (I'm looking to solve), which hook have to use to initialize 'session start ()'?Thank you again!

Comment: Done! add_action ('register_post', 'the_function);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep values in the form after the error message:

```
function my_register_sesion (){
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['key_login']=$_REQUEST['user_login'];
    $_SESSION['key_email']=$_REQUEST['user_email'];
}
add_action ('register_post', 'my_register_sesion');
```

My inputs form should be as follows:

```
<input type="text" name="user_login" id="user_login" class="input" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['key_login'];?>">
<input type="text" name="user_email" id="user_email" class="input" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['key_email'];?>">
```

Thank you David!